# Redux Toolkit keep data across tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a react app using react-redux and redux-toolkit, I'm trying to use react-state-sync npm package to sync my app's data across tabs, however I'm facing some issue. I also tried adding the redux-persist package however it made no difference to the current issue
Here is my code for the store

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};
const reduxStateSyncConfig = {};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);




// first try
export const store = configureStore(
  { reducer: persistedReducer },
  applyMiddleware(createStateSyncMiddleware(reduxStateSyncConfig))
);

// second try
export const store = configureStore(
  { reducer: persistedReducer },
  {},
  applyMiddleware(createStateSyncMiddleware(reduxStateSyncConfig))
);




initStateWithPrevTab(store);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Ever since the state is persisting, I get any new changes on page refresh, however that's about it. The persist package is working fine, though it is something I can remove if needed. It does not work without it either for me. My store is just a simple reducer for count

```
const initialState = {
  value: 0,
};

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

I can't seem to figure this out, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

/Edit/
Link for the npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-state-sync/v/3.1.4

Link for another tutorial I used afterwards

[https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-sync-a-redux-store-across-browser-tabs/#:~:text=Redux%20is%20a%20convenient%20way,in%20their%20other%20open%20tabs](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-sync-a-redux-store-across-browser-tabs/#:%7E:text=Redux%20is%20a%20convenient%20way,in%20their%20other%20open%20tabs).